# Is this a bug in InverseLaplaceTransform?

Tags: numerical-integration

The following produces a nice-looking graph, but I can't find this inverse transform in any of the tables

```
Plot[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[1/s], s, s0], {s0, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is **Not** a bug because give you `INPUT`.Mathematica is not a **magic box** that'll spit out a solution to any problem.All computer algebra systems, including Mathematica, are **limited** in their capabilities.

Comment: See here: https://planetmath.org/inverselaplacetransformofderivatives about **Inverse Laplace transform of derivatives**

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  Thanks for letting me know where this expression comes from. The issue of whether it's a "bug" is really an issue of "should this behavior be changed?", somewhat subjective. I was mainly curious whether these numerical values can be interpereted as the inverse Laplace transform in a more traditional math sense

Comment: If I a give `LaplaceTransform[Exp[t^2], t, s]`. There are two possibilities. 1 doesn't know the answer. 2 doesn't exist.

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work.): `Integrate[Exp[t^2 - p*t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` performs "Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(t (-p+t)) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}."

Comment: Bug report [CASE:5028867]  has been submitted by me.

Answer (score 3):

```
 F[s_] := 1/Sqrt[1/s];
 INV = (-1/s0)*InverseLaplaceTransform[D[F[s], s], s, s0]
 (*-(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] s0^(3/2)))*)

 Plot[{InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[1/s], s, s0], INV}, {s0, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {Dashed, Red}},PlotLabels -> {"InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[1/s],s,s0]", "-(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] s0^(3/2)))"}]
```

[image]

Comment: -1. All that is built on the sand. It's unclear whether `[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[1/s], s, s0]` exists at all. If we use the definition `1/(2*Pi)*
 Integrate[
  1/Sqrt[1/(1 + I*t)]*Exp[(1 + I*t)*s0], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> s0 > 0]`, then Mathematica says "Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(s0+I s0 t) Sqrt[1+I t] does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.".

Comment: @user64494 OP want only function that describe  or produces a nice-looking graph.

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work): As in many cases, your words do not correspond to reality: the question is "Is this a bug in InverseLaplaceTransfom?"

Comment: BTW, `LaplaceTransform[-(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] s0^(3/2))), s0, s]` returns the input, not `Sqrt[s]`.

Comment: @user64494 All computer algebra systems, including Mathematica, are **limited** in their capabilities :P .Use: `f[s0_] := -(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] s0^(3/2)));   Simplify[   I/2*FourierTransform[f[I*s0]*Sign[s0], s0, s,      FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], s > 0]`.

Comment: [Does the inverse Laplace transform of the square root exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138137/does-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-square-root-exist).

Comment: @IAmANaïf: I 'd like to quote the discussion "But there is an equality of divergent integrals $$\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^n} dx=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty x^{n-2} dx $$". Also Anatoly Kochubei does not give any concrete (pages and numbers of formulas) reference.

Comment: @user64494 so this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405242/7655) from the discussion gives a formula for inverse Laplace Transform of square root citing page 36 of Urs Graf

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Not, it is not true. That unaccepted by OP answer is built on the sand  ""But there is an equality of divergent integrals  $$\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^n} dx=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty x^{n-2} dx .""$$

Comment: @user64494 the derivation of that formula is on page 36 Urf Graf's [book](https://mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-35173.pdf).

Answer (score -4):

Let us apply the definition of the `InverseLaplaceTransform` (see [the documetation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html?q=InverseLaplaceTransform)), integrating along the line `Re[s]==1`,

```
1/(2*Pi)*  Integrate[1/Sqrt[1/(1 + I*t)]*Exp[(1 + I*t)*s0], {t,-Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> s0 > 0]
```

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(s0+I s0 t) Sqrt[1+I t] does not converge on {-[Infinity],[Infinity]

In the above $ds=i\,dt$.
Therefore, the inverse Laplace transform under consideration does not exist.

Comment: This is not a proof of anything. For example: `FourierTransform[1/t, t, ω]` exists and is calculated even though `Integrate[(1/t) Exp[I ω t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` complains that the integral does not converge.

Comment: With advice of user: @Domen I compute `LaplaceTransform` by `FourierTransform`: `{Simplify[1/Sqrt[1/s], s > 0], 
 f[s0_] := -(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] s0^(3/2))); 
 Simplify[
  I/2*FourierTransform[f[I*s0]*Sign[s0], s0, s, 
    FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], s > 0]}` looks **True**. :)

Comment: @Domen: First, the  Laplace and inverse Laplace transforms are under the consideration, not a Fourier transform. Second, the Fourier transform of a  tempered distribution  is defined in a complex way. not through  an improper integral (see Tempered distribution in [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) as a first reading)

Comment: What is incorrect in my answer?

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work): Can you explain from where `s0^(3/2))`? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 From Here: `F[s_] := 1/Sqrt[1/s];
 INV = (-1/s0)*InverseLaplaceTransform[D[F[s], s], s, s0]`!

Comment: @user64494 , I gave an example with `FourierTransform` because it is simpler and the same principles seem to apply. If you want `InverseLaplaceTransform`, then please explain why `InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[-s], s, t]` returns `DiracDelta[-1 + t]` yet `Integrate[Exp[-s] Exp[s*t], {s, -I Infinity, I Infinity}]` does not converge.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: You repeat your answer `Plot[INV...]` produces the same as `Plot[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[1/s], s, s0], {s0, 0, 1}]]`  in other formulas. This is not related to my answer that the inverse laplace transform under consideration does not exist.

Comment: "Can you explain from where s0^(3/2))" From Here: `F[s_] := 
 1/Sqrt[1/s]; INV = (-1/s0)*InverseLaplaceTransform[D[F[s], s], s, s0]` !

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: You repeat your answer Plot[INV...] produces the same as Plot[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[1/s], s, s0], {s0, 0, 1}]] in other formulas. This is not related to my answer that the inverse laplace transform under consideration does not exist.

Comment: @Domen: You wrote "If you want InverseLaplaceTransform, then please explain why `InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[-s], s, t]` returns `DiracDelta[-1 + t]` yet `Integrate[Exp[-s] Exp[s*t], {s, -I Infinity, I Infinity}]`  does not converge." I repeat that the Laplace transform of a tempered distribution is defined in a complex way, not through an improper integral as I said about the Fourier transform.

Comment: @user64494, in your answer, you claim that "`Integrate` does not converge $\implies$ `InverseFourierTransform` does not exist". I gave you a counterexample with `Exp[-s]` above, therefore your reasoning is wrong.

Comment: @Domen: I  claim that a usual inverse Laplace transform does not exist. BTW, `LaplaceTransform[-(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] s0^(3/2))), s0, s]` returns the input, not `Sqrt[s]`.

Comment: All integrals not absolutely convergent,  oscillating integrals are rejected by Mathematica There are severe bugs in vs 13.2:  Integrate[Exp[-x^2] HermiteH[122,x] x^18,{x,-oo,oo}]  ->0, NIntegrate complains, but delivers.  Other clearly convergent integrals of the Laplace transform type are rejected as 'non convergent'  InverseLaplace transforms of functons of  sqrt s transform to two Gaussians by s->s'^2 and the general fromula yields a Gaussian convolution with the inverse Laplace transform of the function, a purely text replacement task.